# Send File S3 Access Denied

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm using the same code but is giving access denied. You know how I can do to pass the user has permission. I'm running locally

```
        using (var client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.SAEast1))
        {
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            var strem = File.OpenRead(_repositorioLocal);
            stream.Position = 0;

            try
            {

                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
                request.InputStream = stream;
                request.BucketName = bucketName;
                //request.Grants = new S3Grant({ us})

                request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicReadWrite;
                request.Key = "anexos/" + string.Format("{0}.{1}",idAnexo.ToString(),"pdf");
                var response = client.PutObject(request);

                if (response.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    ret = true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public bool IsBucketExists(AmazonS3Request argAmazonS3Request)
    {
        Boolean l_IsBucketExists = false;

        if (AmazonS3ClientObject == null)
            AmazonS3ClientObject = GetAmazonS3Client(argAmazonS3Request);

        ListBucketsResponse response = AmazonS3ClientObject.ListBuckets();
        IEnumerable<S3Bucket> l_IEnumerableS3Bucket = response.Buckets.Where(bucket => bucket.BucketName == argAmazonS3Request.BucketName);

        if (l_IEnumerableS3Bucket.Count() > 0)
            l_IsBucketExists = true;

        return l_IsBucketExists;
    }

    internal AmazonS3Client GetAmazonS3Client(AmazonS3Request argAmazonS3Request)
    {
        if (AmazonS3ClientObject == null)
        {
            AmazonS3ClientObject = (AmazonS3Client)Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(argAmazonS3Request.AwsAccessKey, argAmazonS3Request.AwsSecretAccessKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        }
        return AmazonS3ClientObject;
    }

    public void CreateBucket(AmazonS3Request argAmazonS3Request)
    {
        AmazonS3ClientObject = GetAmazonS3Client(argAmazonS3Request);

        //ListBucketsResponse response = AmazonS3ClientObject.ListBuckets();
        //foreach (S3Bucket s3Bucket in response.Buckets)
        //{
        //    if (s3Bucket.BucketName == argAmazonS3Request.BucketName)
        //    {
        //        ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
        //        request.BucketName = argAmazonS3Request.BucketName;
        //        ListObjectsResponse listObjectsResponse = AmazonS3ClientObject.ListObjects(request);

        //        foreach (S3Object o in listObjectsResponse.S3Objects)
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", o.Key, o.Size, o.LastModified);

        //            DeleteObjectRequest deleteObjectRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest();
        //            deleteObjectRequest.BucketName = argAmazonS3Request.BucketName;
        //            deleteObjectRequest.Key = o.Key;
        //            AmazonS3ClientObject.DeleteObject(deleteObjectRequest);
        //        }
        //    }
        //}

        if (IsBucketExists(argAmazonS3Request) == false)
        {
            //DeleteBucketRequest deleteBucketRequest = new DeleteBucketRequest();
            //deleteBucketRequest.BucketName = argAmazonS3Request.BucketName;
            //AmazonS3ClientObject.DeleteBucket(deleteBucketRequest);

            // Create bucket
            PutBucketRequest putBucketRequest = new PutBucketRequest();
            putBucketRequest.BucketName = argAmazonS3Request.BucketName;
            putBucketRequest.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
            AmazonS3ClientObject.PutBucket(putBucketRequest);
        }
    }

    public void CreateFolder(AmazonS3Request argAmazonS3Request)
    {
        Boolean IsFolderExists = false;

        AmazonS3ClientObject = GetAmazonS3Client(argAmazonS3Request);

        if (IsBucketExists(argAmazonS3Request) == false)
        {
            CreateBucket(argAmazonS3Request);
        }

        ListBucketsResponse response = AmazonS3ClientObject.ListBuckets();
        foreach (S3Bucket s3Bucket in response.Buckets)
        {
            if (s3Bucket.BucketName == argAmazonS3Request.BucketName)
            {
                ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
                request.BucketName = argAmazonS3Request.BucketName;
                ListObjectsResponse listObjectsResponse = AmazonS3ClientObject.ListObjects(request);

                foreach (S3Object l_S3Object in listObjectsResponse.S3Objects)
                {
                    if (l_S3Object.Key == argAmazonS3Request.FolderName + @"/")
                        IsFolderExists = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (IsFolderExists == false)
        {
            var key = string.Format(@"{0}/", argAmazonS3Request.FolderName);
            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequestFolder = new PutObjectRequest();
            putObjectRequestFolder.BucketName = argAmazonS3Request.BucketName;
            putObjectRequestFolder.Key = key;
            AmazonS3ClientObject.PutObject(putObjectRequestFolder);
        }
    }

    public void PutFileInFolder(AmazonS3Request argAmazonS3Request)
    {
        AmazonS3ClientObject = GetAmazonS3Client(argAmazonS3Request);

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(argAmazonS3Request.FilePath))
        {
            memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
            fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
        }

        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequestFile = new PutObjectRequest();
        putObjectRequestFile.FilePath = argAmazonS3Request.FilePath;
        // putObjectRequestFile.Key = AwsSecretAccessKey;
        m_ObjectKey = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()).Replace("-", string.Empty); // Object key will be used for pre singed public url.
        putObjectRequestFile.Key = m_ObjectKey;
        putObjectRequestFile.BucketName = argAmazonS3Request.BucketName + "/" + argAmazonS3Request.FolderName;
        putObjectRequestFile.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
        putObjectRequestFile.StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard;
        AmazonS3ClientObject.PutObject(putObjectRequestFile);
    }

    public void GetPreSignedPublicUrlOfAmazonS3ile(AmazonS3Request argAmazonS3Request)
    {
        try
        {
            string l_Url = string.Empty;

            // create bucket
            CreateBucket(argAmazonS3Request);

            // create folder in bucket
            CreateFolder(argAmazonS3Request);

            // put file in the folder
            PutFileInFolder(argAmazonS3Request);

            GetPreSignedUrlRequest getPreSignedUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
            getPreSignedUrlRequest.BucketName = argAmazonS3Request.BucketName + "/" + argAmazonS3Request.FolderName;
            getPreSignedUrlRequest.Key = m_ObjectKey;
            getPreSignedUrlRequest.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
            getPreSignedUrlRequest.Protocol = Protocol.HTTP;
            l_Url = AmazonS3ClientObject.GetPreSignedURL(getPreSignedUrlRequest);

            argAmazonS3Request.PreSignedPublicUrl = l_Url;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            AmazonS3ClientObject.Dispose();
            AmazonS3ClientObject = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might want to add an explanation.